# Add two strings containing binary numbers

Tags: java, string

I'm teaching myself how to code with java and I use exercises I find in the Internet to practice what I learn.

Anyway, I'm in a middle of an exercise that asks me to build a method that get two strings containing only the characters "0" and "1" from the user and returns one string of them both (binary)combined

example:

```
BinaryAdder("0","0") - > "0"
BinaryAdder("1","1") - > "10"
BinaryAdder("10100","111") - > "11011"
```

what I did is:

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class assigment03
{
    private static String whichIsBigger(String a, String b)
    {
        if(a.length()>b.length())
            return a;
        if(a.length()<b.length())
                return b;
        if(a.length()==b.length())
            return a;
        else return null;
    }



private static String binaryAdder(String a,String b)
{

    int[] binaryResult= new int[maxlength(a,b)+1];
    String result="";

    if(whichIsBigger(a,b)==a)
    {
        for(int i=0;i<b.length();i++)
        {
            binaryResult[i]=a.charAt(i)+b.charAt(i);
        }
        for(int i=b.length();i<a.length();i++)
        {
            binaryResult[i]+=a.charAt(i);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        for(int i=0;i<a.length();i++)
        {
            binaryResult[i]=b.charAt(i)+a.charAt(i);
        }
        for(int i=a.length();i<b.length();i++)
        {
            binaryResult[i]+=b.charAt(i);
        }
    }
    for(int i=0;i<binaryResult.length-1;i++)
    {
        if(binaryResult[i]>=2)
        {
            binaryResult[i]=binaryResult[i]%2;
            binaryResult[i+1]++;
        }
    }
        for(int i=binaryResult.length-1;i>=0;i--)
        {
            result+=Integer.toString(binaryResult[i]);
        }
    return result;

}

private static int maxlength(String a, String b)
{
    if(a.length()>b.length())
        return a.length();
    else
        return b.length();
}
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner temp= new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print(binaryAdder(temp.next(),temp.next()));
}
}
```

But it doesn't return the right result.
Do you mind help me out here?

thanks a lot!

Comment: Can't you just parse as integer, add, and covert back to binary?

Comment: You can't use `a.charAt(i)+b.charAt(i)` - this gives the ASCI value for the `char`.

Comment: few hints, when comparing String values, never use the == operator, instead use the equals() method, since == operator compares 2 objects in memory, while the equals() method compares if both objects are meaningfully equal or not (even if both are 2 different Objects in memory),second thing, when using the if - else, always use the braces to make your code easier to read and also easier to maintain

Comment: You have many problems, one of which is `whichIsBigger()` - if the strings have the same size it doesn't mean that "a" can be returned as "bigger. example: a="10"  b="11". Second, you should add digit by digit, right to left, like you do in "regular" addition, and don't forget the carry-over!

Comment: Further, when you do something like `a.charAt(i)+b.charAt(i)` you add chars instead of digits. Use a debugger or print out to log/screen - it'll help you figure out the root of the problems.

Comment: Is there some maximum for possible input values or can the input strings be arbitrary length?

Answer (score 0):

Reading your question, I understood that you might be looking for some help implementing the methods to actually add two binary numbers, and then giving back the result in base two (which btw might be complicated in Java). However, I believe that this exercise lacks of a very important restriction like the what is max length allowed for the binary numbers to be read (overflows can arise while processing the values with primitive data types like int or String). Also this exercise needs some planning when dealing with none significant zeroes like in these cases because "00110b" = "0110b" = "0110b" and when dealing with rolling over the carry of any addition that yields 2 ("10b") or 3 ("11b"). More information on those topics can be found **[here](http://www.springer.com/engineering/circuits+%26+systems/book/978-1-4614-3142-8)**, in chapter 2.

At least in Java, when tackling these type of exercises, an option is to avoid dealing with such restrictions and conditions. Java provides a class called **[BigInteger](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html)** that takes care of huge values, none significant zeroes, and the carries taking away the burden of dealing with those things from the programmers. Java BigInteger also offers a constructor that can initialize their objects in any base. (Well not any, there are some restrictions to this too, please see this **[link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#MAX_RADIX)** for more information).

With that said, here is my solution to this exercise:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.math.BigInteger;

public class BinaryAdder {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        ArrayList<String> numbers = new ArrayList<String>();
        String number = "";
        int count = 1;

        System.out.print("Instructions:\nPlease enter a set of binary numbers. When you are ready to calculate their addition, enter \"done\",\n\n");
        System.out.print("Number " + count + ": ");

        while(!(number = scanner.next()).equals("done")){
            numbers.add(number);
            count++;
            System.out.print("Number " + count + ": ");
        }

        System.out.print("Result = " + binaryAdder(numbers) + "b");

        scanner.close();
    }

    public static String binaryAdder(ArrayList<String> numbers){
        BigInteger accumulator = new BigInteger("0");

        for(String number: numbers){
            accumulator = accumulator.add(new BigInteger(number, 2));
        }

        return accumulator.toString(2);
    }
}
```

**Example:**

> Instructions: Please enter a set of binary numbers. When you are ready
>   to calculate their addition, enter "done",
>
> Number 1: 00001
>   Number 2: 011
>   Number 3: done
>   Result = 100b

Between lines 8-11 some variables are declared: a ***scanner*** to read the binary numbers entered, an ***array list*** to store the binary numbers entered, a ***string*** to hold a number once is entered, and a ***int*** to keep track of how many numbers have been entered, since I extended this solution to add 0,1,2,3,...,n numbers).

Line 13 prints the instructions of this solution. Line 14 only prints "Number 1: ".

The while loop between lines 16-20 sets the value entered to the variable *number* and checks if it is equal to "done". Given the case it steps out of the loop, otherwise, it adds the number to the *array list*.

Line 22 prints the result of the addition of all the binary numbers entered.

But the "magic" really happens between lines 27-35 in the method "binaryAdder" (Note that "binaryAdder" receives that ArrayList holding all the numbers entered as a parameter). At line 28 an accumulator of type BigInteger is initialized to zero to hold the addition of all the numbers in the ArrayList. Then, a for loop travels through all the numbers in the array list to add them to the accumulator. Finally, the accumulated value is returned in base two.